# Jquery UI dialog displayed behind ascx popup

Tags: jquery, master-pages, ascx

I have a jquery ui dialog in the master page for the session time out, but dialog appears behind the ascx contol popup when the session times out. I tried using $("#selector").dialog("moveToTop"), but its not working. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Pay close attention to the `z-index` of the elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: If you using the asp.net webforms, you need to declare the element with id 'selector' inside the master page, outside the user control.